# HighCharts: Drilldown to a Stacked Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

**Hi everyone!** I am trying to create a certain `HighChart`, but I am not sure on how I should format my `drilldown` data and I can't find any example on the internet!

This JSfiddle shows how far I have gotten: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/37/.

The HighChart is suppose to visualise comments that have been deleted. The first two bars are mean amounts of filtered comments. When the drilldown is activated, I would to have stacked columns of websites and four categories of why a comment has been filtered (nasty comments, spam etc).

Could someone help me out with this or have an example of how to format the drilldown data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a stacked column you need multiple series, to have multiple series after the drilldown you have to add the series dynamically, e.g. on drilldown event.

Each property of the object below represents a series and it is associated with the top level series name.
Object '1' will appear after the click on the first column and will span 4 categories.

```
var drilldowns = {
          1: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            name: 'facebook',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [
              ['nasty comments', 2],
              ['spam', 3],
              ['category-3', 10],
              ['category-4', 15]
            ]
          },

          66: {
            name: 'second-column-drilldown',
            data: [
              ['second-column-drilldown-point', 10]
            ]
          }
        };
```

The next object '1' will be stacked with the data from the `drilldowns.1` object:

```
var drilldowns2 = {
          1: {
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            colorIndex: 1,
            stacking: 'normal',
            name: 'youtube',
            data: [
              ['nasty comments', 5],
              ['spam', 10],
              ['category-3', 10],
              ['category-4', 15]
            ]
          }
        };
```

And finally the series must be added and the drilldown is fired.

```
var series = drilldowns[e.point.name],
            series2 = drilldowns2[e.point.name],
            series3 = drilldowns3[e.point.name];

        this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
        this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series2);
        this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series3);
        this.applyDrilldown();
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahjkouuh/

Comment: Thank you! I will test it rn!

Comment: Awesome! I edited the code a bit so it would accept JSON data from files and it works great! Only struggling a bit with the colors, but that can be fixes! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to include the drilldown js (http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/38/)

Add the following script after highstock : 
`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>`

EDIT : Sorry I didn't read the question right... This works : http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/39/

Found here : http://www.semantia.com.au/articles/highcharts-drill-down-stacked-columns/

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get this to work too but not stacked. Could you help me out with this?