# How to open a page when highcharts stacked bar is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am creating a stacked bar chart with help of `highcharts`.

When I click on any part of bar I want to open a new page that displays containing data. How can I achieve this?

As shown in this image the graph is not stacked as it should be. It is displayed as different three vertical bars. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Stacked column chart with data from MySQL using   Highcharts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Account Status',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'No of Accounts'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
             plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [],
                plotOptions: {
                seriessss: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                events: {
                click: function () {
                document.location.href = 'page.php?cat=' + this.category;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0     auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you include the second image? You might want to take a look at the drilldown module. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown It allows you to drill into more detailed data without reloading the page.

Comment: @morganfree drilldown allows us to drill down descriptive chart. But here i am showing the chart of accounts completed in a week. When clicked on chart, i want to show the list of accounts in that category for that week. is it possible with drilldown? if u want to have a look at the image i want. here is the link https://s17.postimg.org/5c7kl4yyn/Capturen.jpg  thanks !

Comment: Try to dislplay in the tool tip only, or else you can try including the html <a> give the link to the page you want to dislplay, when u click on tool tip

Comment: It is possible. You are looking for drilldown to a stacked chart. Check the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676122/highcharts-drilldown-to-a-stacked-column/40683153#40683153