# Two series bar chart in drilldown charts in Asp.Net C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I need to add the drill-down charts in my ASP.NET project. So now I am using highcharts.

The requirement is:

1. Pie chart
2. Two series bar chart (For ex, 2 bars for a month)

When I drill-down from level 1 (pie), level 2 (two series bar) should be displayed.

But I can only add single bar charts. How can I add the two series bar charts in level 2?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the info. Halfer

Comment: You need to add series dynamically with [addSeriesAsDrilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown) function. You can see the answer from this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676122/highcharts-drilldown-to-a-stacked-column/40683153#40683153 - all you need to do is adjust the type series and their number - https://jsfiddle.net/ahjkouuh/12/

Comment: Thank you Morgan.

Comment: Can' we change it to bar charts. Its one above another. Its type is column, then why it is showing one above another. can you please explain it. I am new to this.

Comment: Can we create drilldown charts with solidgauge or speedometer

Comment: This is a stacking property. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.stacking You can disable it by removing it from the series options. Drilldown gauges seem to be wortking - http://jsfiddle.net/ddx8fv22/